# What is the while loop's function in PathIterator?

Tags: java

http://java-sl.com/tip_flatteningpathiterator_moving_shape.html

Trying to study this code in the link above but I am having trouble understanding the following code:

```
    float[] coords=new float[6];
    while (!iter.isDone()) {
        iter.currentSegment(coords);
        int x=(int)coords[0];
        int y=(int)coords[1];
        points.add(new Point(x,y));
        iter.next();
    }
```

What is the purpose of the `float` array, and why is there 6, and how does this increments in the `while` loop to move an object along a shape's path?

Comment: Would the basis of this code be a good start to make a track car game. I want to build a mulitplayer app with multiple cars on a track that will have different speeds other factors, the gui will be very similar to this program.

Comment: The `FlatteningPathIterator` replaces curve segments with many short straight ones. If your race track has straightaways, these are returned unchanged.  This means the distance between the returned points can vary greatly. If you traverse the returned points at a constant rate, your speed will vary.  Your game may need to post process the returned points, to generate a new set with your own criteria, such as one point per 10 meters of track.  Then, the car's distance travelled would easily convert to a display position.  Basis for a game?  No.  Basis for racetrack design to game model?  Sure!

Answer (score 3):

A `Path` is defined by multiple segments, which can be:

- `SEG_CLOSE` (0 coordinates)
- `SEG_MOVETO` (2 coordinates: x, y)
- `SEG_LINETO` (2 coordinates: x, y)
- `SEG_QUADTO` (4 coordinates: x1, y1, x2, y2)
- `SEG_CUBICTO` (6 coordinates: x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)

(`SEG_LINETO`, `SEG_QUADTO` and `SEG_CUBICTO` segments also have an implicit starting point: the end of the previous segment)

For example, a triangle might be made from the the following:

```
GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
path.moveTo(10, 10);
path.lineTo(15, 20);
path.lineTo(20,  8);
path.close();
```

The `while(!iter.done()) { }` loop processes each segment of the path in turn, starting with the `SEG_MOVETO`, followed by a `SEG_LINETO`, a second `SEG_LINETO` and lastly the `SEG_CLOSE`.

The `coords[]` array is used as temporary storage, for the output of the `currentSegment()` call.  Instead of allocating storage for each segment as it is returned, the temporary storage array is overwritten.  Since a "cubic" segments need 3 points (6 coordinates), the array size must be at least 6.

The code you posted includes an implicit assumption - that only `SEG_MOVETO`  / `SEG_LINETO` type segments are present, so only `coord[0]` and `coord[1]` will ever be valid.  This seems like a safe assumption, since the `FlatteningPathIterator` (shown in the linked text, not the question text) should never return a curved segment.  But, it also includes a more dangerous assumption that a `SEG_CLOSE` segment will never appear, which has 0 coordinates and could result in garbage corrupting the resulting `points` list.

Better code might read more like:

```
float[] coords = new float[6];
while(!iter.done()) {
    int type = iter.currentSegment(coords);
    if (type == SEG_MOVETO || type == SEG_LINETO) {
      int x = (int) coords[0];
      int y = (int) coords[1];
      points.add(new Point(x,y));
    } else if (type == SEG_CLOSE) {
      // Handling sub-path closing here
    }
    iter.next();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(for context) `iter` is an instance of `FlatteningPathIterator` (that's important to explain all the `iter` calls!)

`float[] coords=new float[6];` Initializes a new `float` array, with 6 indexes, with default value (0.0f)

```
   while (!iter.isDone()) {
        ...
        iter.next();
    }
```

Here `iter` is a `PathIterator` instance. So `iter.next()` moves the iterator pointer to the next item in the iterator, and `iter.isDone()` checks if there is anything left in the iterator.

And lastly, `iter.currentSegment(coords);` loads the contents of the current iterator segment to the `coords` array.

Comment: Would the basis of this code be a good start to make a track car game. I want to build a mulitplayer app with multiple cars on a track that will have different speeds other factors, the gui will be very similar to this program.

Comment: @AJNeufeld That would be a question for AJ. I understand the concept of an Iterator, and reading the API. AJ seems to actually understand what it is trying to do on a higher level.